# Sort By Descending Date Django

Tags: python, django

models.py

```
class Record(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    ....

class Balance(models.Model):
    record = models.ForeignKey(Record)
    ....
```

views.py

```
balances = Balance.objects.filter(record__date__week=current_week).order_by("-record")
```

this will order the balance entries based on when the records were created not on the date from Record. How can I sort these queries for Balance based on Record Date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the date field of the record to ordering:

`balances = Balance.objects.filter(record__date__week=current_week).order_by("-record__date")`

Comment: Worked like a charm. Appreciate that.